# Как разработчики приложений показывают уведомление от приложения?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, уведомления

Доброй ночи! Давно задался этим вопросом, как можно отобразить уведомление от приложения?
С сообщением тут всё ясно, искал в документации API, толком ничего не нашел, либо искал плохо. В скриншоте показал пример

[image: пример 1]

[image: пример 2]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Возможно это? https://vk.com/dev/secure.sendNotification